# Slick slider - how to exclude certain divs from a slider?

Tags: slider, slick.js

I am using the slick slider from https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ which is quite a nice slider overall. Is there a way to slide only certain div-s which are inside the whole slick-initialized div? In other words, here is a sample structure:

```
<div class="sliderdiv slick-initialized slick-slider">
<div class="slick-list">
<div class="slick-track">
<div class="slick-slide">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="not-to-slide">              
            <h2>Some Title</h2>
                <div class="somedeeperleveldiv">
                    <span>some text</span>
                </div>
        </div> <!-- end of divs that do not have to slide //-->
        <div class="slideable">
            <div>
                <div>
                some image or text
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slideable">
            <div>
                <div>
                some image or text
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The slider is initialized by:

```
$('.sliderdiv').slick({
            some options
        }).slick(slickFilter, '.slideable');
```

I've tried SlickFilter as in .slick(slickFilter, '.slideable'); but it gives `ReferenceError: slickFilter is not defined`

Is there a way to exclude the "not-to-slide" class div and everything that is inside that div from the slider? The idea here is to have only divs of class "slideable" to be used as slides.

A more general solution in case such "not-to-slide" divs appear inside divs that are to be slided would also be appreciated.

Comment: I'm sort of running into a similar issue, except slick is applying slider attributes to `<style/>` and `<script/>` tags and I want it to not do that and ignore those.